C2PA validator extension for Firefox (open source, gratis)
Chrome has https://github.com/digimarc-corp/c2pa-content-credentials-extension to validate Coalition for Content Provenance and Authenticity (C2PA) validity, in other words detect AI-generated images/etc.
Is there a similar extension for Firefox?
Must be gratis and open source, so https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ai-detector-winston-ai is not a solution.
